# log notebook as html using snakemake (not only as ipynb)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, snakemake, nbconvert

I tried snakemakes jupyter notebook integration and I like to have a saved notebook for the rule which can be executed easily anywhere! The [docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#jupyter-notebook-integration) are great for this!

I wonder if there is also an integrated way to log the html version of the notebook, or if this has to be done manuelly through a custom rule doing that. The notebook is executed and saved using `jupyter nbconvert` which also has `--to html` as an option.

```
# example of what snakemake executes, taken from the logs,
# note: full-paths omitted (but used by snakemake 7.8.2)
jupyter-nbconvert --log-level ERROR --execute --output "example_notebook.ipynb" --to notebook --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=-1 "output_dir/example_notebook.ipynb"
```

Happy for any hints if this is possible out of the box in snakemake.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not implemented, but would be nice to implement.

Comment: So a rule which does the transfer has it problems in detecking crashes: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/683

Comment: Interesting, well, as a hack one could require not just the log notebook but also the related output...

Comment: I added a note to the issue: github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/683